# Error injecting ejb to jsf managed bean

Tags: java, netbeans, primefaces

I'm developing an enterprise web application using netbeans, and making use of primefaces and mysql. However, I have encountered a problem which is caused by trying to inject the ejb to the jsf managed bean. 
In my war file, i have my .xhtml and managed bean.

loginBean.java (managed bean)

```
package jmbean;

@ManagedBean(name="loginBean")
@SessionScoped
public class loginBean implements Serializable{

    @EJB
    private UserBeanLocal ub;

    @Resource(name="jdbc/his")
    private DataSource ds;

    private String uname;
    private String password;

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public String getUname() {
        return uname;
    }

    public void setUname(String uname) {
        this.uname = uname;
    }

    public String login() throws NamingException {
        boolean result;
        try {
            Connection con=ds.getConnection();
            PreparedStatement ps=con.prepareStatement("select user, pass from userinfo where user= ? and pass= ?");
            ps.setString(1, uname);
            ps.setString(2, password);
            ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
            if (rs.next()) // found
            {
                System.out.println(rs.getString("user"));
                result=true;
            }
            else {
                result=false;
            }
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            System.out.println("Error in login() -->" + ex.getMessage());
        }

        if (result=true) {
            // get Http Session and store username
            HttpSession session = (HttpSession)FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getSession(false);
            session.setAttribute("username", uname);

            return "home";
        }
        else {  
            FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(
                    null,
                    new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_WARN,
                    "Invalid Login!",
                    "Please Try Again!"));
            return "login"; 
        }  
    }

    public String logout() {
      HttpSession session = (HttpSession)FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getSession(false);
      session.invalidate();
      return "login";
   }

    /**
     * Creates a new instance of loginBean
     */
    public loginBean() {
    }
}
```

in my ejb file, i have my session bean and entity.

UserBean.java (session bean)

```
package sbean;

import javax.ejb.Stateless;

@Stateless

public class UserBean implements sbean.UserBeanLocal {

}
```

When i run the application, it gives me the following error:

> Error occurred during deployment: Exception while loading the app :
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start:
>   org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: java.lang.RuntimeException:
>   java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Lsbean/UserBeanLocal;

Any help on this? Thanks.

Comment: Seems like deployment error. `sbean.UserBeanLocal` interface is not deployed to the server.

Comment: Did you create and deploy the EJB Jar? Is the JAR inside the JSF project?

Comment: @PiotrGwiazda why would it not have been deployed to server?

Comment: @Jessai how do i know if the JAR is inside my project?

Comment: Check in WEB-INF/lib/ folder of your project. You have to do it manually, no automatic things. Also check your project Libraries, the EJB Jar has to be added there too.

Answer (score 0):

1. Stop your server.
2. Right click on  project-jar(Project Browser)
3. Clean and build.
4. Right click on  project-war(Project Browser)
5. Clean and build.
6. Run your Project.
   I hope that this solves your problem